# Anyone tried to Juggernaut with php (nodejs)

Tags: node.js, comet, juggernaut

I am trying to make a real-time publish/scribe module using juggernaut(nodejs plugin)
Juggernaut's client is usually Ruby not php. but, my project's main language is php.
so I have to make some php things.

Clients Subscribing is okay, it's very easy.
But, the problem is **Publish**, and write message.

After long googling, 
I found out that Juggernaut do not allow client's direct publish.
So, I made a conclusion.

Publish machanism : 
**client's Javascript -> Php(Phpredis) -> Juggernaut DB(Redis) -> Juggernaut**

and then **Juggernaut publish to every subscribers**.
But, the 4 step is too many things -_-;
My thought is right or wrong? I can't find any hint from [Juggernaut github](https://github.com/maccman/juggernaut).

any comments welcome~

Comment: Can you talk more about what you are trying to accomplish? php talking to a node server? browsers talking to a php server which then talks to a node server which then publishes to other servers? Your question is a bit confusing for me.

Comment: Might take a look at [backbone-redis](https://github.com/sorensen/backbone-redis) as it may be simpler for you to use.

Comment: confusing~ Sorry for that, Dtrejo. I am tring to make real-time boards. any user who are viewing the board page can see new writings without page refreshing. so I want to use Juggernuat for that.

Comment: Just so you know, it is possible to use [socket.io](http://socket.io/) across domains, allowing you to keep your php server 100% separate from your node server, making a triangle instead of a complicated chain. This may be what you're looking for. Also, stop into [#node.js](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=node.js&uio=d4) and ask questions for a quicker response :) Make sure to report back with your findings.

Comment: I've tried backbone-redis examples, todos. it's works, great. But I have some questions about this with my project. New board writings are saved in mysql server via php server-side language. So, backbone-redis module have to know them in real-time to update view pages. is it possible? is this right mechanism you suggest? thanks DTrejo~

Answer (score 0):

That question is related to this question, [juggernaut file serving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7280811/juggernaut-file-serving)

this way is good to go. 
you can find the solution in there.
Hope this help guys~ ^^;